# Pandas Dataframe: Show duplicate rows - with exact duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big dataframe (120000x40) and I try to find duplicates in every row and display them. Thats what I tried:

### create dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['1-233','2-766g','6-455','4-356','5-253','2-122','5-531','8-345','1-505','3-127','3-622'],
'col2':['6-998','2-766g','5-955','7-236','5-253','7-258','8-987t','7-567','1-505','6-876','NaN'],
'col3':['3-957','NaN','NaN','3-602m','1-266','2-122','7-834','8-345','2-858','7-984g', 'NaN']})

## code
df["duplicate"] = df.apply(lambda x: len(set(x[x.notna()])) != len(x[x.notna()]), axis=1)

print(df)
```

#output:
[image: output_code1]

But what I wanted was the folling:
[image: wanted_code]
To see what exactly is doubled here.

Comment: I see in the image there is no space  in `8- 345`. So I assume there is a type in your example and I have coded accordingly and edited your question, let me know if that isn't a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the function readable and general, so it works for more or less than three cols, I'd just rely on writing a dedicated function that uses pandas built in functionality for finding duplicates, and applying that to the dataframe rows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['1-233','2-766g','6-455','4-356','5-253','2-122','5-531','8- 345','1-505','3-127','3-622'],
'col2':['6-998','2-766g','5-955','7-236','5-253','7-258','8-987t','7-567','1-505','6-876','NaN'],
'col3':['3-957','NaN','NaN','3-602m','1-266','2-122','7-834','8-345','2-858','7-984g', 'NaN']})

def get_duplicate_value(row):
    """If row has duplicates, return that value, else NaN."""
    duplicate_locations = row.duplicated()
    if duplicate_locations.any():
        dup_index = duplicate_locations.idxmax()
        return row[dup_index]
    return np.NaN

df["solution"] = df.apply(get_duplicate_value, axis=1)
```

Check out the docs of `pd.Dataframe.apply`, `pd.Series.duplicated`, `pd.Series.any` and `pd.Series.idxmax` to figure out how this works exactly.

Output:

```
      col1    col2    col3 solution
0    1-233   6-998   3-957      NaN
1   2-766g  2-766g     NaN   2-766g
2    6-455   5-955     NaN      NaN
3    4-356   7-236  3-602m      NaN
4    5-253   5-253   1-266    5-253
5    2-122   7-258   2-122    2-122
6    5-531  8-987t   7-834      NaN
7   8- 345   7-567   8-345      NaN
8    1-505   1-505   2-858    1-505
9    3-127   6-876  7-984g      NaN
10   3-622     NaN     NaN      NaN
```

Comment: I'm still pretty frustrated that Python doesn't appear to offer a way to implement this `get_duplicate_value` function that could be understood without consulting docs. Check out @ouroboros1's answer for an implementation that is slightly more readable than this.

Comment: Hey @Joooeey the idymax function gives me exactly the values that appear most often. Is there also a possibility to display all duplicate values - especially useful when several duplicates appear in a series. I would also like to count them. Thank you for any advice :)

Comment: Just `return set(row[duplicate_locations])`.

Comment: Than its giving me this: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterabl. If I use: set[duplicate_locations], it is giving me the count of the set but not the duplicate itself.

Comment: I just tested it and it works for me. Where is the `None` coming from?

Comment: Sorry, worked for me too after I started the program again. Don#t know where the problem was but the "have you tried turning it off and on again" is always performing well.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Nested ternary operator`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html) to iterate through your rows and get the duplicate values.

```
import numpy as np

df['Solution'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.col1 if row.col1 == row.col2 else row.col2 if row.col2 == row.col3 else row.col3 if row.col3 == row.col1 else np.NaN, axis=1)
```

which gives us the expected output

```
df
      col1    col2    col3 Solution
0    1-233   6-998   3-957      NaN
1   2-766g  2-766g     NaN   2-766g
2    6-455   5-955     NaN      NaN
3    4-356   7-236  3-602m      NaN
4    5-253   5-253   1-266    5-253
5    2-122   7-258   2-122    2-122
6    5-531  8-987t   7-834      NaN
7    8-345   7-567   8-345    8-345
8    1-505   1-505   2-858    1-505
9    3-127   6-876  7-984g      NaN
10   3-622     NaN     NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Thank you, thats working too! But I have a very big df and not always the same amount of columns.

Comment: Of Course! Thank you for your time! Sorry that was my first question and I was quite overwhelmed how fast people where helping while I'm just trying to figure out how this platform works (upvotes, accept answers, checking wich code works for me). :)

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this by using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the `collections` module.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['1-233','2-766g','6-455','4-356','5-253','2-122','5-531','8-345','1-505','3-127','3-622'],
'col2':['6-998','2-766g','5-955','7-236','5-253','7-258','8-987t','7-567','1-505','6-876','NaN'],
'col3':['3-957','NaN','NaN','3-602m','1-266','2-122','7-834','8-345','2-858','7-984g', 'NaN']})

def funct(row):
    if Counter(row).most_common(1)[0][1] >= 2:
        return Counter(row).most_common(1)[0][0]
    return np.nan

df['duplicate'] = df.iloc[:,:3].apply(funct, axis=1)

print(df) 
# N.B. I've changed the entry "8- 345" in `col1` to "8-345" 
# (the space appears to be a typo, judging from your prints).

      col1    col2    col3 duplicate
0    1-233   6-998   3-957       NaN
1   2-766g  2-766g     NaN    2-766g
2    6-455   5-955     NaN       NaN
3    4-356   7-236  3-602m       NaN
4    5-253   5-253   1-266     5-253
5    2-122   7-258   2-122     2-122
6    5-531  8-987t   7-834       NaN
7    8-345   7-567   8-345     8-345
8    1-505   1-505   2-858     1-505
9    3-127   6-876  7-984g       NaN
10   3-622     NaN     NaN       NaN
```

E.g. for row `1`, `Counter(row).most_common(1)` will get us: `Counter({'2-766g': 2, 'NaN': 1})`. We want to check if the first (most common) value >= 2, so `Counter(row).most_common(1)[0][1]`. If so, the associated key will be your duplicate value. Else, we return `np.nan`.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a second data frame and then inserting a new row into it with the duplicate values gives the required output.

```
column_names = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "duplicate_values"]
duplicated_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
# code
for row in df.itertuples(index=True, name="Pandas"):
    seen = []
    ColumnIndex = int
    FOUND = False
    for j, value in enumerate(row):
        if value in seen:
            ColumnIndex = j
            FOUND = True
            break
        seen.append(value)
    DuplicateValue = "NaN"
    if FOUND:
        DuplicateValue = row[ColumnIndex]
    new_row = {
        "col1": row.col1,
        "col2": row.col2,
        "col3": row.col3,
        "duplicate_values": DuplicateValue,
    }
    # append row to the dataframe
    duplicated_df = duplicated_df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

print(duplicated_df)
```